# What can I get from a struct pointer?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, pointers, struct

I'm overriding a method that takes a struct pointer as an argument. I don't have the declaration of the struct so I have no idea of it's size etc. What can I find out about a struct from just a pointer to it?

Comment: You have to have the definition of the struct if you want to do anything with the pointer.

Comment: If you know that it is taking a pointer to a struct, don't you know what kind of struct it is?

Answer (score 15):

> What can I find out about a struct from just a pointer to it?

Nothing.

This pattern, [opaque pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer#C), is used to hide implementation. The fact that you can infer nothing about what is behind the pointer is in fact by design.

Comment: That's correct if it's a `void*` or `char*`.  Pretty much any other kind of pointer you can deduce _something_ about.

Comment: If I don't know it's size can I print out it's starting point in memory + an arbitrary size?

Comment: And yes, it's got opaque in it's name. What does that mean?

Comment: @MooingDuck, please explain. A pointer of an incomplete type in C, doesn't tell you more than eventually its type name, no?

Comment: If the only thing you have is a forward-declaration in a header file (e.g. "struct Foo;") then the only thing you can deduce is the name of the type.  To find out more you would need access to the definition of the struct as well (which is often deliberately hidden in a .c/.cpp file specifically to keep you ignorant of details that might change in a later version ;))

Comment: @All: Whoops, forgot about forward declarations.  If it's forward declared, you're hosed.

Comment: @user1000039 The opaque means that you are not intended to look inside. You don't need to look inside.

Comment: @user1000039: There's no requirement that the numerical value of a pointer has anything to do with physical memory. As far as the standard goes, it simply "points to a variable". As long as you don't know that it has a valid value, you can't do anything with it.

Comment: Yep. It's forward declared. Is there nothing I can do?

Comment: @user1000039 What you do is faithfully pass it on to the other functions that request it as a parameter. You don't need to look inside.

Comment: @MooingDuck: You may be handed a non-null pointer to a structure and you could be still unable to even call `sizeof(*p)` because the struct could be an "incomplete type". Pointers to incomplete types are often used for the "Compiler firewall" / "PIMPL" pattern.

Comment: Would going to the assembly level help understand the struct? I'm trying to call a method that takes this struct as a pointer, but I have no idea what it does

Comment: @user1000039 Does this method that you want to call really not have any documentation? If you want to reverse engineer some code then knock yourself out.

Comment: Nope. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: @user1000039 What you could do would be to use libraries that are supplied with documentation, or reverse engineer the code with the aid of a debugger and strong knowledge of machine language.

Comment: I have a knowledge of machine language but not a debugger. If I wanted to print the struct using the debugger what could I do?

Comment: I meant knowledge of how to use it

Comment: I can't explain that in comments. I think I answered this question already.

Comment: What could I find out about the struct using a debugger?

Comment: You could see its contents. You don't even need a debugger for that. Just cast the pointer to `char*` and print out some bytes. You'd really need to debug the code to try and reverse engineer this I guess. What on earth are you doing anyway? Why do you not have any documentation?

Comment: With the debugger I just get "$1 = <incomplete type>"

Comment: Please take any extended discussion to [chat]. If there is a specific question here, of course asking it as a question would be better.

Comment: I can't teach you how to use a debugger in comments. I think I answered the question as well as I can.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only using a pointer you don't need the size.  If you really want to know what's there, use gdb, stop somewhere you have a live pointer, and dereference it (`p *myStruct`).

Comment: The executable has had it's debug symbols stripped. I can't attach gdb

Comment: You can absolutely attach gdb to a process without gdb symbols. You can also still print the pointer as suggested.